# How do I remove all hyperlinks that begin with a #?

Tags: facebook, regex

Facebook's Instant Articles rejects articles that contain hyperlinks to the current page (e.g. `<a href="#_ftn1">[1]</a>`). How can I filter the post content to remove these links before publishing to Facebook Instant Articles?

I'm aware of a similar question on StackOverflow: [How to remove hyperlink of images in wordpress post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282580/how-to-remove-hyperlink-of-images-in-wordpress-post), but my RegEx skills aren't good enough to convert that to what I need.

PS - I'm using the semi-official [Instant Articles for WP](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/), which means I can filter `instant_articles_content`.

PPS - It would be nice to know both how to remove the link but leave the link text, and how to remove both the link and the link text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @Samuel Elh, but accounting for single or double quoted attributes and a `href` that might not be the first attribute of an anchor:

```
function wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks( $content ) {
    preg_match_all( '!<a[^>]*? href=[\'"]#[^<]+</a>!i', $content, $matches );

    foreach ( $matches[0] as $link )
        $content = str_replace( $link, strip_tags( $link ), $content );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks' );
```

<strike>Note this will completely remove the link node/HTML from the post content.</strike> This will replace the HTML link with just the inner text.

Comment: This works well, but I'd appreciate an alternative which removes the link but retains the link text. I could use WordPress' wp_kses function, but that's probably overkill...

Comment: Just add `strip_tags`, see revision

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Interconnectit DB Search/Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to search and replace all instances of strings in your database. This may not fully solve your problem, but you could start with searching for `<a href="#` and replacing it with `<a href="`.

I don't think that's exactly what you're trying to do, but hopefully it's a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks( $content ) { 

    preg_match_all( '/<a href=\\"([^\\"]*)\\">(.*)<\\/a>/iU', $content, $matches );

    foreach( $matches[0] as $link ) {

        preg_match_all('/(?<=href=\").+(?=\")/', $link, $matches2);
        $href = isset( $matches2[0][0] ) ? $matches2[0][0] : false;

        if( 0 === strpos($href, '#') ) {

            $content = str_replace( $link, strip_tags($link), $content );
        }

    }

    return $content;

}
```

Hook it into your content filter e.g `add_filter(tag_name, 'wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks')`. You should remove the filter (with [remove_filter()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) e.g `remove_filter(tag_name, 'wpse_227315_strip_hyperlinks')`) after you post to Facebook.

Comment: Why are you regexing _all_ links & iterating & regexing _again_ for the hash? Just use the hash regex to begin with and iterate => replace

Comment: @TheDeadMedic lol I am really new to Regex I couldn't put together such expression but I'll try again and edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, I'm surprised you're new to it! I've also posted an answer to illustrate.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the answer, it helped me and it should help the question author as well :)

Comment: The code isn't working reliably for me. Using simple test data, it's fine. But using it with one of my actual posts, and the first preg_match_all function returns an empty array.

Here's a Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8vjk-n0wx